# Javascript migrating from XMLHttpRequest to CloudflareBypasser

Tags: javascript, html, npm, cloudflare

Ive been trying to talk to this webpage which uses cloudflare. So far,m code is:

```
var b = new XMLHttpRequest;
    
b.open("GET", bUrl + a, !0), b.onload = function() {
    if (b.status >= 200 || b.status <= 400) {
        var a = document.createElement( 'html' );
        a.innerHTML = b.responseText;
        a.getElementsByTagName( 'a' )
        console.log(a), manageData(a), console.log(fLink)
                
    } else console.log("Bad response from server.")
}, b.send()
```

And while this has proved to work, recently the Cloudflare put up by the site has inhibited my program from running. Because of this, I want to replicate exactly what this code snippet did, except using this [Cloudflare bypassing repository](https://github.com/Kamikadze4GAME/cloudflare-bypasser) instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. So far, I have this:

```
const CloudflareBypasser = require('cloudflare-bypasser');
var b = new CloudflareBypasser();

b.request(bUrl + a).then(res => {
    var a = document.createElement( 'html' );
    a.innerHTML = res.responseText;
    a.getElementsByTagName( 'a' )
    console.log(a), console.log(res.responseText), manageData(a), console.log(fLink)
});
```

does anyone know how i could seamlessly accomplish this?

Comment: So what happens when you run the new code?

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan it still says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`

Comment: What is not working exactly? Is there an error?

Comment: @epascarello Thats just to execute multiple funtions in one line. The 403 code means it was blocked by cloudflare, so i still haven't gotten it quite right